# How can I implement a "Nyan Cat" rainbow?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, objective-c, arcade

I'm currently making a game similar to this [Nyan Cat flash game](http://www.scumlabs.com/misc/nyan-cat-flash-game/), although I'm using cocos2d. I'm having a hard time trying to make the rainbow effect:

[image]

Currently, every update call I add a piece of rainbow on screen and move it back, having also added it into a special array. When a player changes its `y` coordinate I rotate all the added spites by a certain calculated value.

Honestly, it looks... not perfect and I've been wondering if there is better way?

Comment: Think you can add an appropriate image instead of a link to a flash site? That would help this question stay useful.

Comment: Most likely the issue comes from you just rotating the sprites. I don't know if Cocos2d has something built in to help with rail rendering but if it does not you can make the curve piece by drawing the rainbow tile as a pie slice rather than an actual tile. I can't say I know the math behind this, but I'm guessing your issues come from drawing the tiles over one another. Without a image or a better explanation of what your issue looks like I can't really suggest anything more than that.

Answer (score 3):

There's a special class available in cocos2d that renders a ribbon of quads for you. At one point it was named `CCRibbon`, but I think it has been changed to `CCMotionStreak` ([docs](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_motion_streak.html)). It's designed to render trails or ribbons. I think using that class would be the most efficient way to create such an effect.